# Does Qt slots run in parallel with other code?

Tags: c++, qt

On this function example:

```
void MyClass::myFunction()
  {
    emit MySignal1();
    emit MySignal2();
  }
```

If I have `slot1` listening for `MySignal1`, and `slot2` listening for `MySignal2`:

1) Is `slot1` going to be always executed before `slot2`?

2) Will one slot be executed until the other one finishes? Or can both slots run in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slots are invoked in the order they are connected to the signal. And are invoked at the time of emit; so in your case (ignoring threads) the slots connected to the first signal will run before those connected to the second (for Qt 4.6+, before that the order was undefined).

The slots *may* run on other threads (and thus execute concurrently) - see  (for example) http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads for details.

Comment: @Paul : http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#signals - prior to Qt 4.6 the order was undefined, but from 4.6 onwards the order is guaranteed to be the order in which slots were connected. Relevant quote from previous link: "If several slots are connected to one signal, the slots will be executed one after the other, in the order they have been connected, when the signal is emitted." .

Comment: Yep, already found it myself. I remember it was undefined at some point, so I was confused.

Comment: The order of the different slots connected to the same signal was undefined, but the order of the emits has never been undefined ASAIK, your sentence is not really clear to me.

Comment: As well slots are called from the event loop and not directly invoked from the emit.

Comment: @Damien That depends on whether it is a "direct" or a "queued" connection.

Answer (score 6):

The answer entirely depends on how the signals are connected to their respective slots: Assuming both signals are connected once to *the same object's* slot, then: The invocations are *always in order* (assuming you don't do something weird.. but then you would know already.. like if you filter out `QEvent::MetaCall` events.. which is definitely *not recommended*).

If they are connected with `Qt::QueuedConnection`, the emissions *always immediately return* and don't wait for the invocations to finish.

You can use `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection`, and then the emissions *wait* for the invocations to return (this can only be used if the destination object is in a different thread than the currently running thread and the destination object's thread has a running event loop - otherwise a deadlock occurs!).

For a `Qt::DirectConnection`, both emissions will become *simple function calls*, so the sequencing follows trivially for that case.

---

If you have *different objects*, then if you use `Qt::DirectConnection`, you still have sequenced executions.

Otherwise, for `Qt::QueuedConnection` or `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` and the destination objects live in the same thread, the same thing applies as above for the same-object case. If they live in different threads, for non-blocking queued connections, you have no order guarantees.. the slots may execute concurrently. For blocking queued connection, you again have ordered execution.